# How to create json file ( with array type object) dynamically using python

Tags: python, arrays, json

I am trying to create below json file with some array object dynamically :

```
{
  "timestamp": "Timestamp",
  "year":"2020"
  "actions": {
    "copy": {
      "id": [1,2]
    }
  }
}
```

where only id would be generated dynamically. I tried to create the below code but got some issue . Any suggestion please :

```
import json
import os


def write_json():
    # create a dictionary
    data = {
        "timestamp": "Timestamp",
        "year":"2020",
        "actions": {
          "copy":    {
            "id": []
    }
  }
}
    #create a list
    data_holder = data["name"]
    # just a counter
    counter = 0
    while counter < 2:
        data_holder.append({counter})
        counter += 1
    #write the file
    path = os.getenv("HOME")
    file_path=path+'/'+'data.json'
    with open(file_path, 'w') as outfile:
        print("writing file to: ",file_path)
        json.dump(data, outfile)
    outfile.close()
    print("done")

write_json()
```

Comment: _I tried to create the below code but got some issue_ Are we supposed to guess what the issue was?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
def write_json():
    # create a dictionary
    data = {
        "timestamp": "Timestamp",
        "year": "2020",
        "actions": {
            "copy": {
                "id": []
            }
        }
    }

# additional code here...

with open("FILE PATH HERE", 'w') as outfile:
    x = json.dumps(data)
    outfile.write(x)

outfile.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    write_json()
```

which works for me using a valid file path.